# Find the length of largest subarray with equal number of 0's and 1's using recursion

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, function, recursion

Given an array with just `0's` and `1's` find the length of the largest subarray with equal number of `0's` and `1's`. For example, given an array

```
011110001
```

the largest subarray with equal number of `0's` and `1's` has the length 8, from index 0 to index 7.

Write a **recursive** function `largestSubarray`. This function takes 3 inputs: an array - A, the index of its first element – start, the index of its last element – end, and returns the size of the largestSubarray. If no subarray with equal number of `0's and 1's` is found, the function should return 0.

```
int largestSubarray(int * A, int start, int end){
  int i, j=0, k=0;
  for(i=start; i<=end; i++){
    if(arr[i]==0){
     j++;
    }
    else if(arr[i]==1){
     k++;
    }
    if (j==k){
return (end+1-start)+largestSubarray(array, start+1, end);
    }

   }
```

How can I fix this code? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please add more details to your questions so others can help (ex. Language, SDK)

Comment: Yes, it's C problem

Comment: What's the problem, more exactly? What happened when you ran this through your debugger?

Comment: This probably isn't the only problem, but I noticed that your `for` loop terminates too early. Replace `i<end` with `i<=end`.

Comment: @IanAbbott ??? the common way if `i < end` so how do you know this information ?

Comment: @Stargateur If `end` was one past the end of the array then `i < end` would be correct, but according to the given instructions, `end` is the index of last element of the array. Therefore the `for` loop needs to count from `start` to `end` **inclusive**. Therefore, it needs to use `i <= end`.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you got the problem worked out. Recursion can provide elegant solutions for those tasks where it is uniquely suited, or where a procedural solution cannot be reasonably written. Each recursive call is a separate function call requiring a complete separate function stack. That can rapidly eat up, and exhaust, available memory as the number of recursions increases. A procedural solution should be preferred.

Also, your array `011110001` must be a shorthand for an array holding the values

```
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

on it own, `011110001`, is the *octal constant* for `2396161`.

Here, finding the largest balanced subarray of zeros and ones could be done just as easily with a loop. However, understanding it was a practice exam question, it has educational value.

A clean solution would be to write a `largestsubarray` wrapper function to call a second recursive function passing an integer pointer for `size` as an extra parameter for the internal call. By providing a single address holding size, you eliminate the chance the value is overwritten as the recursion unwinds.

In a single function, the key is to force each recursive call to return, otherwise you will experience problems overwriting `size` as the recursive functions unwind. One implementation could be:

```
/* end must be ending index -- not size */
int largestsubarry (int *a, int start, int end)
{
    int o = 0, z = 0;       /* ones, zeros */

    if (end <= start)
        return 0;

    /* count the ones and zeros in subarray */
    for (register int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (a[i] == 1)
            o++;
        else if (a[i] == 0)
            z++;
        else
            o = z = 0;      /* reset on any other value */
    }

    if (o != z) {   /* ones & zeros not equal */
        int s = largestsubarry (a, start + 1, end), /* test eliminating */
            e = largestsubarry (a, start, end - 1); /* each end */

        if (s > e)  /* return largest */
            return s;
        else
            return e;
    }
    else    /* balanced sub-array found, return size */
        return o + z;
}
```

(**note:** while not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.)

**Example Use/Output**

Passing integer arrays containing the following values results in locating the proper size of the largest balanced sub-array of sequential zeros and ones, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/subarray
enter array (ctrl+d ends): 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
size: 8

$ ./bin/subarray
enter array (ctrl+d ends): 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
size: 8

$ ./bin/subarray
enter array (ctrl+d ends): 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
size: 10

$ ./bin/subarray
enter array (ctrl+d ends): 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
size: 6

$ ./bin/subarray
enter array (ctrl+d ends): 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 2
size: 0
```

There are probably more efficient ways of doing it, but the key is knowing which end to eliminate to find the longest balanced sub-array.

Comment: I think `register` is a key word ignore by 100% of actual compiler ;), like you decide to give the solution here mine, http://rextester.com/PLPMIN90543

Comment: Hey, I like that, you took the wrapper function route. This was actually one of those annoying brain-teasers, that are really kinda fun, if for no other reason they get you out of the norm, and make you think your way out of chasing your tail around the problem `:p`

Comment: @Stargateur, check your code with `1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1`, it is doing something funny. It is returning `zero = 4, one = 4, i = 2, n = 10`, the longest balanced subarray is `8`, so it looks like `'i'` needs to have something done with it?

Comment: Sorry, my code wasn't really supposed read by someone else that me, I do it yesterday for fun, I like recursion ^^, `i` is the index where the subarray begin and `n` is the end of the subarray, so `n - i` give the size so in your case `10 - 2 == 8`, that is correct that give the subarray `0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0`.

Comment: No complaints, I like the approach. I was just wondering about the `10-2 = 8` issue. It looked like you had it sorted out, and I could see that, but was just a bit confused with the output. Thanks for posting and dropping a link.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is obviously a coding challenge, I'll just provide a guideline of one way to solve it.

1. Count the number of 1's and the number of 0's. If they match, return the length of the array: `end+1-start` since this is the longest balanced subarray.
2. Recursively call with `largestSubarray(array, start+1, end)` and with `largestSubarray(array, start, end-1)` and return whichever of those is the highest number.

There are probably more efficient ways to solve it, but that's part of the challenge!

EDIT

One simple improvement is to check the length of the array before counting the 1's and 0's. If the length is odd, there is no point counting them (assuming those are the only possible values in the array), so you can skip straight to step 2 if the length is odd.

Comment: It's question from practice exam for my midterm. It's not the homework or anything I need to turn in.Would you able to  give full solution please?